# 404 error after hosting website developed using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to develop an web application that takes google address and stores for future use..

I am a little new to codeIgniter and a little help would be appreciable...
I have developed the application in WAMP 2.0..

It works fine there..But when I upload it to a production server, it displays the index page..but as soon as I try to navigate to other pages from the home page it gives a
404 Page Not Found..

You can always check the site  [here](http://www.poimart.com)..

The entire application is working fine in my localhost that is in WAMP..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may be to do with case sensitivity in *nix and windows environments.

this link works:

`http://www.poimart.com/index.php/poi/create_user`

but this doesn't (404s) (no capital P)

`http://www.poimart.com/index.php/Poi/create_user`

so any references to your pages within your app should have lower case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ross for replying...But why is there a diff of case sensitive..?? Then how come in windows it runs properly..??

Comment: on windows, `INDEX.php` is the same as `index.php` (any file name/ext). On *nix they are completely different. I imagine your hosting is linux -hence this problem, If you were using it on windows hosting (i.e your local machine) then you wouldn't notice a problem more @ http://mark.koli.ch/2009/03/filename-case-sensitivity-another-annoying-linux-vs-windows-difference.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if any `.htaccess` file exists in your document root?

Comment: I was bugged with it..!! So i thought that it may be a problem because of 'index.php' that occurs there..So the day after I faced the problem I uploaded the .htaccess file which removed the 'index.php' from the URI..Now it work fine...Its all about the case sensitivity....;-) Thanks Padmanabha Vn for replying...